# Linq VB.net to PowerShell 5.1

Tags: vb.net, powershell, linq

I have a Linq query in VB.Net which works fine.
I now need to transform this to work in PowerShell by using the static Linq methods.
I figured out how to do simple select and where queries but especially the grouping and "new with" I am not sure how to translate...
The goal is to find out if the entries (dataRows) in a Data Table that do have the same AttributeKey also have the same AttributeValue AndAlso the same AttributeType or not.

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("AttributeKey")
        dt.Columns.Add("AttributeValue")
        dt.Columns.Add("AttributeType")
        dt.Rows.Add("Action", "MakeItSo", "System.String")
        dt.Rows.Add("Action", "MakeItSo", "System.String")
        dt.Rows.Add("Action", "True", "System.Boolean")
        dt.Rows.Add("Single", "MyVal", "System.String")

        Dim srcGroupBy = dt.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(Function(Attrib) New With
        {
            Key .AttributeKey = Attrib.Field(Of String)("AttributeKey")
        }).
            Where(Function(grp) grp.Count() > 1).
            Select(Function(grp) New With {
              Key .AttributeKey = grp.Key.AttributeKey,
              Key .CounterVal = grp.GroupBy(Function(AttributeVal) AttributeVal.Item("AttributeValue").ToString().ToUpper()).Count(),
              Key .CounterType = grp.GroupBy(Function(AttributeType) AttributeType.Item("AttributeType").ToString().ToUpper()).Count(),
              Key .ExistsInInconsistentStates = grp.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Item("AttributeValue").ToString().ToUpper()).Count() > 1 Or
                grp.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Item("AttributeType").ToString().ToUpper()).Count() > 1
             })
```

I could also solve this without Linq in PS like this:

```
[PSObject]$res=$DV | 
    Group-Object -Property "AttributeKey" | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$PsItem.Count -gt 1} |
    Select-Object -Property @("Name","Count",@{Name='CountDistinctVals';Expression=`
    {
        $PsItem.Group.AttributeValue | 
        Select-Object -Unique | 
        Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count"
    }`
    },@{Name='CountVals';Expression=`
    {
        $PsItem.Group.AttributeValue | 
        Select-Object | 
        Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count"
    }`
    },@{Name='CountDistinctTypes';Expression=`
    {
        $PsItem.Group.AttributeType | 
        Select-Object -Unique | 
        Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count"
    }`
    },@{Name='CountTypes';Expression=`
    {
        $PsItem.Group.AttributeType | 
        Select-Object | 
        Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count"
    }`
    })
```

I can then evaluate the first row and check if distinct count = all count which would also meet my requirement for that particular use case.
Anyway, it would be still interesting for me to know whether it could be done also in Linq with PS. (Not saying that this would always be the preferred way)

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Is using Linq methods a hard requirement? PowerShell's own core cmdlets largely mimic the query-pipeline-like behavior you get out of Linq anyways, eg. `$dt |Group-Object AttributeKey |Where-Object Count -gt 1 |ForEach-Object { <# create output object here #> }`. Linq methods on the other hand are an absolute pain because PowerShell tends to unroll anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: If you are looking to use LINQ you're likely going to end up just using C# which doesn't have that much to do with PowerShell.

Comment: ok thanks. Will then try to do it the PS way first. Anyway, would still be interesting to use the static [System.Linq.Enumerable]:: methods in a nested way to translate a Linq query to PS...